# If I create my own DNS with a domain name how do I prevent somebody else from copying my DNS?

Tags: networking

For example, how does the internet prevent someone from creating their own DNS and creating a copy domain name of "www.google.com" directing traffic from the website on "www.google.com" to the copy DNS of "www.google.com"?

Answer (score 3):

The DNS namespace is delegated hierarchically: `.` (root) name servers delegates the control for `.com` which delegates the control for `example.com` etc.

Of course *recursive* name servers may spoof the results. To prevent this, DNSSEC was invented. It allows signing of the records and is also hierarcical.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. so as I understand your comment, a DNS has it's own form of authentication certificate (like SSL uses)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you get "ownership" of a domain through a Domain Registrar, you get to say which is the authoritative DNS server for that domain you own.

Each host connecting to the Internet will have some sort of "DNS Client" that will start all queries from a trusted set of "root servers". These do not know about any user-level domains, but they keep a list of top level domains (like `.com`, `.net`, and country suffixes like `.ar` for Argentina which are called CCTLD for Country Code Top Level Domain). In turn, each CCTLD will handle their top level domains below it (like `.org.ar.` which is reserved for non-profits in Argentina). Each country has a set of rules: in our case in Argentina a govenment organization called "nic.ar" will handle `org.ar` and it knows what server is the authoritative for each domain.

In the case of `huesped.org.ar`, which is a large AIDS non-profit here, they have it handled Amazon, it seems. Here I am using a Linux DNS client and querying from the top (`.`) and asking for the `SOA` record of each domain, which is "Start of Authority" and tells you which server is responsible for that.

```
user@p-2018d:~$ host -t SOA .
. has SOA record a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2018081000 1800 900 604800 86400
user@p-2018d:~$ host -t SOA com.
com has SOA record a.gtld-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1533992426 1800 900 604800 86400
user@p-2018d:~$ host -t SOA ar.
ar has SOA record c.dns.ar. noc.nic.gob.ar. 2018081109 43200 3600 1728000 86400
user@p-2018d:~$ host -t SOA org.ar.
org.ar has SOA record c.dns.ar. noc.nic.gob.ar. 2018081110 43200 3600 1728000 86400
user@p-2018d:~$ host -t SOA huesped.org.ar.
huesped.org.ar has SOA record ns-1524.awsdns-62.org. awsdns- 
hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

So, in short, the domain owner is allowed to establish the authoritative source of information for their domain.

Anybody can put a DNS server and answer whatever they like, but no one would ask them for that information. Unless, of course, there is some sort of malware on the enduser computer, or someone messing with their traffic.

You may want to research for "Domain hijacking", which is the term used to refer to the practise you are worried about, and will give you specific information about how to reduce the chances of that happening to your domain.

Hope the explanation did not confuse you more :-)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you're currently *trusting* the DNS server *and* your ISP whenever you make a DNS query.

The DNS protocol [RFC 1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) is unencrypted and can be imperceptibly proxied, monitored and altered without difficulty at the upstream ISP level. [DNSSEC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2535.txt) does not eliminate this fundamental trust issue because all of the validation information can be tampered with as well although it does add some additional work.

When a user inputs `www.google.com`, a DNS name, their computer sends a DNS protocol query to the DNS servers that are configured in that computer's IP settings to retrieve the IP address(es) for `www.google.com`. It's not uncommon for some ISPs to intercept the unencrypted DNS queries and reply with their own *customized* responses. c.f [Cox](https://www.bing.com/search?q=cox+dns+hijacking), [Spectrum](https://www.bing.com/search?q=spectrum+dns+hijacking), [AT&T](https://www.bing.com/search?q=at%26t+dns+hijacking)

One common recommendation is to manually replace the DNS Server addresses that you receive from an ISP with a trusted DNS server from a major company like:

1. Google's

   - ipv4 `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4`
   - ipv6 `2001:4860:4860::8888` & `2001:4860:4860::8844`
2. Cisco's OpenDNS [https://opendns.com]

   - ipv4 `208.67.222.222` & `208.67.220.220`
   - ipv6 `2620:0:ccc::2` & `2620:0:ccd::2`

Unfortunately, without end-to-end encryption of a protocol, you're still in a position of trusting the carrier and DNS server.

There are several solutions to the end-to-end encryption problem.

- VPN to a network with a DNS server that you trust.
- Use [DNSCrypt](https://www.opendns.com/about/innovations/dnscrypt/)
- Wait for [DNS-over-TLS](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7858.txt) to be more widely implemented.

Comment: This "common recommendation" assumes that you trust Google more that your ISP (your ISP can redirect the DNS requests anyway without you noticing), and that you want Google to know your DNS queries.

Comment: DNSSEC does in a way solve this because, if the zone is protected by it, and the recursor validates the answer with its local trust anchor, then any change of the zone content at any level from the zone up to root will be detected.

Comment: There are many more others public recursors: 1.1.1.1 (CloudFlare), 9.9.9.9 (Quad9), FreeNom, etc... I personnally prefer a local validator instead of using a public one. Also with DNS over TLS or over HTTPS, which is becoming the default with Firefox for example, the data is encrypted in transit.

Comment: With DNSSEC validation, it's certainly detectable, however I don't think most users are going to be able to rely on a local trust anchor since they are going to have to rely on the ISP for the initial resolution.